# 2D Drawing in Netbeans 6.x

Tags: java, netbeans, 2d

How can i draw 2d in a JPanel that i have on my GUI? I can do it in eclipse but am having trouble doing it in netbeans. I've looked for some tutorials but the only good one i found was for netbeans 5.5 ([world's fasted java netbeans 5.5 tutorial](http://wws2.uncc.edu/tpw/tpwJavaNtebeansTutorial/index.html)) and i guess netbeans removed some of the things needed for that tutorial.

Comment: How is your IDE choice affecting your ability to use Java2D? What are you doing in Eclipse that is failing in Netbeans?

Comment: At which step do you have a problem in the tutorial?

Comment: Which is why you should learn how to do it without an IDE so you understand the code and you can take your knowledge from one tool to the other.

Comment: I can do it in Eclipse...which doesn't generate GUI. I get stuck on the adding an inner class step.

Comment: *Do not directly edit the Matisse GUI code*. Make a subclass of it and expose all the controls and event handlers you need to through that code. You will have to the event handlers and controls as *protected* for this to work. Unfortunately, the NB IDE will not let you edit the access modifiers on the event handler stubs so you will need to find a way (such as using a different editor) to change the access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to the formview where you can edit your frame.
2) Select your panel
3) Click right and select costumize code
4) Add an override:

```
panel = new JPanel()
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        drawPanel(g);
    }
}
```

5) Create the `drawPanel(Graphics g)` method.

Comment: Actually custom painting should be done by overriding the paintComponent() method, not the paint() method.